# Can I render tables and/or charts 'side by side' in an xls report using DynamicJasper?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I'm building a reporting application that's using **DynamicJasper** for exporting data to xls. The reports are pretty dynamic in the sense that the user is able to customize the queries (one or more) that fetch the data. The resulted data can be rendered as a table or as a chart.

Currently the tables and the charts (pngs) are rendered one after the other, in order, in a 'one column' layout. I would need to add support for a 'two column' layout. For example, to be able to have the tables/charts rendered side by side.

I have to mention that I'm using the **DynamicReportBuilder.addConcatenatedReport** API. No jasper-reports templates are being used.

Are there any solutions to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not supported.
It could maybe achieved with sub-reports, but coding is needed. not easy

Comment: Can you please pinpoint the area where coding would be needed? Is it just a DynamicJasper limitation that requires library changes? Or this can be achieved with plain Jasper API? Thanks!